# How can i download a certain file into a specific folder using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

assuming my link is : `web_link = 'https://link'`
and my destination file that i want the content to be downloaded in is `path`.
How can i download the content of `web_link` in `path` knowing that i'm using python2.7.

Comment: You don't do `web_link = 'https://link'` if you want to download the file in the `link` folder. you simply do `web_link = 'link/'`

Comment: I checked that answer and few others before i post here, it just didn't work as there was no path to where he wanted to download his content(in my case .flac files)

Comment: David, not sure about that, what if i wanted to download my content from a gs://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download using urllib:-

### Python 2

```
import urllib 
urllib.urlretrieve("web_link", "path")
```

you can use `requests` if weblink needs authentication :

```
import requests
r = requests.get(web_link, auth=('usrname', 'password'), verify=False,stream=True)   #Note web_link is https://
r.raw.decode_content = True
with open("path", 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

### Python 3

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("web_link", "path")
```